# Is there an iOS equivalent to Maps SDK for Android's PolyUtil?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

In the Android version of the app I'm working on, I've used `PolyUtil` [from the Maps SDK for Android Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility) to decode a polyline and show it on a map.

Now I'm working on the iOS version of this, I can't find anything like `PolyUtil` in the [Maps SDK for iOS Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility).

Is there something I'm missing or a quick way to implement this? Manually implementing the algorithm seems like a lot of work for such a basic function.

Comment: The Apple Maps framework does not have inbuilt support for polyline. You can add a [line](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpolyline) as an overlay but you would either need to parse the string yourself or find some 3rd party library.

Comment: @Paulw11 The question concerns Google Maps not Apple Maps.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted to be closed. It would be helpful to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found an equivalent to `PolyUtil` or another reliable way to decode the encoded polyline, so instead of requesting the encoded polyline I had to set `polylineEncoding: "GEO_JSON_LINESTRING"` in the request body, and `routes.polyline.geoJsonLinestring` (note the capitalisation on `Linestring` - it's not `LineString` as referred to elsewhere) in the requested fields header, then loop through the coordinates in the response.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/reference/rest/v2/TopLevel/computeRoutes#polyline